# Prebid JS integration with Pulsepoint exchange

Tags: javascript, prebid.js

I am trying to integrate Prebid.js for the 3 bidders AppNexus, Pulsepoint and Rubicon. I am able to successfully configure AppNexus but I cannot see the bids in the Developer Tools Console.
I tried adding Pulsepoint and every time I get "Bid returned empty or error response" as a response.

Did I do something wrong or miss something in below configuration?

```
var adUnits = [{
    code: 'div-gpt-ad-1471847819782-0',
    sizes: [[728, 90]],
    bids: [
            {
                bidder: 'pulsepoint',
                params: { 
                  cf: '728X90',
                  cp: 558725,
                  ct: 497758
                }
            }
    ]
}];
```

Comment: According to http://prebid.github.io/dev-docs/bidders.html#pulsepoint  those are the correct params. Did you contact PulsePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind sometimes that bidders will need to whitelist domains associated with parameters in order for them to work. I’d reach out to Pulsepoint directly to get some specific parameters for your domain.